# Avoid Unity UI event callback chain

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, events

How can I prevent in Unity this situation (A should react on C event but A know instance of B and B know an instance of C) :
In the situation below, A creates instances of B that creates instances of C, now C are UI elements with buttons that get the event on click.
In this case, B just "pass the event" to A that have to react to the event.
I want to try to avoid this.
One solution could be to create an "eventManager" singleton that dispatches all events to registered objects ... but I don't like singleton so much.

```
Class A : Monobehaviour
{
    Start()
    {
        GameObject bGO = InstantiateGameobject();
        B b = bGO.GetComponent<B>();
        b.m_onButtonClicked += DoSmthinA;
    }

    private DoSmthinA
    {
        Log("A";)
    }
}

Class B : Monobehaviour
{
    public event System.Action m_onButtonClicked;

    Start()
    {
        GameObject cGO = InstantiateGameobject();
        C c = cGO.GetComponent<C>();
        c.m_onButtonClicked += DoSmthinB;
    }

    private DoSmthinB
    {
        Log("B";)
        m_onButtonClicked?.Invoke();
    }
}

Class C : Monobehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Button m_button; 
    public event System.Action m_onButtonClicked;

    Start()
    {
        button.onclick.addlistner(OnButtonCLicked);
    }

    private OnButtonCLicked
    {
        Log("C";)
        m_onButtonClicked?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a singleton event manager is probably my choice. That being said, you can also pass a reference of A to B when it is created, and then pass it all the way down to C when it's created. Then you can expose DoSmthinA as public, and call it directly from button C.

Comment: One solution is to store a reference to the parent UI element on creation, then when an event occurs send a message recursively up to each parent until the recipient is reached. This would provide a standardized way of propagating events back the chain.

Comment: ErikOverflow thank you for your suggestion, I  missed to say that dependency injection with public methods is a solution that I'm not looking for.
I was wondering if there is a "best practice" for this situation, may be provided by Unity? using EventSystem maybe?.
@Arc2066 thank you for your suggestion, is there a method in Unity for propagating events up in hierarchy? 
Is there a standard way to do this in Unity?

Comment: Unity does have two standard ways of doing this that I know about. For each way their is a version that targets a single gameobject and another that will propogate up if it doesn't hit a target. They are Gameobject.SendMessage() and GameObject.SendMessageUpwards(),  EventSystems.Execute() and EventSystems.ExecuteHierarchy(). The second one is new I believe. You may want to create your own interface that stores direct references if you need more speed as these methods are loosely coupled and slow.

Comment: Documentation Links: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MessagingSystem.html 
 
https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.html 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html